# YouTube iOS Player Helper do not show playerView

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube

I have a question in embedded youtube-ios-player-helper in my work.
When I follow the steps in https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper?hl=zh-tw
(Adding a YTPlayerView via Interface Builder or the Storyboard)
I've finished the procedure from step 1 to step 3.
On step 4, "In Interface Builder, create a connection from the View element that you defined in the previous step to your View Controlle r's playerView property."
when I use ctrl and drag the view controller from the bottom to the selected View in the view controller region. The outlets only display "view", not "playerView and view" as illustrated in the photo of the link. Therefore, I couldn't get the youtube video in the selected View elements in the storyboard. What is wrong with my action?

Answer (score 0):

try to get it from the file's owner , not the uiview - that worked for me - [image]